# Watir-Webdriver limited functionally issue

Tags: watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the code that is below everything works expect for the last line. I do not get an error, but the line of code in not working. How do I fix this problem?

```
require "watir-webdriver"
test = "test"
ia1 = "http://" + test + "mypurefleet.pureenergyservices.com/"
e = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
e.goto(ia1)     
e.frame(:name => "content").text_field(:name => "txtPwd").set "name"
```

When I run the code in IRB I get the following response.

```
[14.628][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[14.628][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[14.658][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[14.659][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[14.659][INFO]: sending WebDriver response: 200 {
   "sessionId": "65f50d0fd6ce5acad36bf310db8a7ef",
   "status": 7,
   "value": {
      "message": "no such element\n  (Session info: chrome=27.0.1453.110)\n  (Dr
iver info: chromedriver=2.0,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)"
   }
}
[14.667][INFO]: received WebDriver request: POST /session/65f50d0fd6ce5acad36bf3
10db8a7ef/element {
   "using": "xpath",
   "value": ".//frame[@name='content']"
}
[14.669][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[14.670][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[14.688][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[14.688][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[14.689][INFO]: sending WebDriver response: 200 {
   sessionId: 65f50d0fd6ce5acad36bf310db8a7ef,
   status: 0,
   value: {
      ELEMENT: 0.1280214337166388:1
   }
}
.
.
.
.
.
[15.000][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[15.001][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[15.025][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[15.025][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[15.026][INFO]: sending WebDriver response: 200 {
   "sessionId": "65f50d0fd6ce5acad36bf310db8a7ef",
   "status": 0,
   "value": null
}
[15.032][INFO]: received WebDriver request: POST /session/65f50d0fd6ce5acad36bf3
10db8a7ef/element/0.24873712522143:1/value {
   "value": [ "name" ]
}
[15.033][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[15.034][INFO]: done waiting or pending navigations
[15.092][INFO]: waitingforpendingnavigations...
[15.093][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[15.093][INFO]: sending WebDriver response: 200 {
   "sessionId": "65f50d0fd6ce5acad36bf310db8a7ef",
   "status": 0,
   "value": null
}
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>
```

Answer (score 3):

Works fine here on mac:

```
MEDBEDbs-iMac:~ medbedb$ irb
1.9.3p392 :001 > require "watir-webdriver"
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > test = "test"
 => "test" 
1.9.3p392 :003 > ia1 = "http://" + test + "mypurefleet.pureenergyservices.com/"
 => "http://testmypurefleet.pureenergyservices.com/" 
1.9.3p392 :004 > e = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x..fbf7bb9bed066d83c url="about:blank" title="about:blank"> 
1.9.3p392 :005 > e.goto(ia1)     
 => "http://testmypurefleet.pureenergyservices.com/" 
1.9.3p392 :006 > e.frame(:name => "content").text_field(:name => "txtPwd").set "name"
 => {} 
1.9.3p392 :007 > e.frame(:name => "content").text_fields.each { |p| puts p.html }
<input type="text" name="txtUser" size="20" maxlength="60" title="User ID">
<input type="password" name="txtPwd" size="20" maxlength="40" title="Password">
 => [#<Watir::TextField:0x..f95bb2b33ebcdbb2e located=true selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>, #<Watir::TextField:0x130f931c73c6f6f8 located=true selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>]
```

Try updating the [chromedriver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list), also try this:

```
gem update --system
gem update
```

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.0.0, do you know if that may be causing the problem?

Comment: Looks like it's a chromedriver specific issue, tried that in win, works fine with firefox, but returns exception in chrome .. You might wanna fill in a bug on this .. (Win7; Ruby 1.9.3; same error). Try "e = Watir::Browser.new :ff" as a temporary workaround.